# Regular expression to remove class attribute from tr tag

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, html-table

I have a series of tables, and I want to remove a specific class from the class attribute of tr tags using a regular expression in Visual Studio's Find/Replace dialog window. If a class attribute only contains the target class (e.g. "orgtemplate_tableentry"), I would like to completely remove the class attribute from the "tr" tag; however, I would like to keep the class attribute if additional classes are contained in the class attribute. The following RegEx finds the target tr tags, but that's it; it works in VS Enterprise 2015:

```
<tr[^>]+class\b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(<tr[^>]+class="(nameOfClassToRemove))
```

For backend use with c# try this:

```
var html = "your string of html like <tr class="abc">....";
var regexStr = "(<tr[^>]+class=\"(nameOfClassToRemove))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @regexStr);

if(matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
       if(match[1] != null)
       {
           var newClassName = match.Value.Replace(match[1], string.Empty);
       }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this but it would give you an idea.
It would be better if you do this on the front end with javascript though. The logic would be similar.

**Some Explanation:** 
The regex will pick up 2 groups, 
1st will be the code with the class (tr class=") and the second group the class name to remove.

Then you just replace the class to remove with an empty string.

Comment: your `regexStr` is broken, escape the second `"`

Comment: yes you need to escape. Just add a forward-slash in the inside quotes. Like var regexStr = "(<tr[^>]+class=\"(nameOfClassToRemove))";

Answer (score 0):

You can use the look behind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` operators to achieve this.

Try matching and replacing the class name in the following match: `(?<= <tr class=")(.*)className(.*)(?=")`

Comment: Your RegEx didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Techie2015 I've made some updates to it. Is is still not working?

Comment: Please send a screenshot of your VS environment if it works for you.

Comment: @Techie2015 the updated answer should match the entire class name that contains the class your looking for. You'll just have to remove the class name your looking for in the match.